# Copy the current file name to the clipboard

Tags: macos, vim, clipboard

How can I send the current buffer's filename to the clipboard from Vim on OS X.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

does this help you?

```
:let @+=expand('%:p')
```

if you need do this often, create a map.

Comment: It does! That's better than what I came up with. If anyone is wondering, you can get a relative path by removing the `:p`.

Answer (score 2):

This will do it

```
:!echo -n % | pbcopy
```

- `%` stands for the current buffer's filename in Vim.
- `echo -n %` will print the current file name without a newline char at the end.
- `|` will pipe the output of the above expression to the following command
- `pbcopy` adds stuff to the clopboard on OS X.

You can map this to a handy shortcut by putting this in your `.vimrc`

```
nnoremap <leader>f :!echo -n % \| pbcopy<cr>
```

Comment: Twitter was the other tab.

Comment: Shelling out to external tools should only be necessary in the (unlikely) case that your Vim isn't built with clipboard support.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following in my `~/.vimrc` file:

```
" yank a register into another register
" ["x]yr{reg}
nnoremap <silent> yr :call setreg(v:register, getreg(nr2char(getchar())))<cr>
```

This allows me to copy a register to another register. I typically use this to copy the `@%` register to the unnamed or system clipboard. e.g. `"+yr%`. However I have found it useful to copy the `@.` and `@:` on rare occasion.

Answer (score 0):

On OSX. To copy the fullpath to the clipboard, you can use

`:!echo %:p | pbcopy`

Then you can paste it anywhere (including vim)